# PHP mysqli SELECT query won't execute

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, where-clause

```
$dc=fopen("numeu.txt","rb");
$row1=fgets($dc,120);   
$row2=fgets($dc,120);
$row3=fgets($dc,120);

fclose($dc);

$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password='';
$database="Stildev";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$sql="SELECT poza1,poza2,poza3,poza4,poza5,poza6 FROM postari WHERE utilizator='".$row2."' AND subiect='".$row1."' AND id2='".$row3."'";


$resultat=$conn->query($sql);

echo $resultat->num_rows;
```

This piece of code returns 0 rows

There is no error and sql query works just fine in MySQL console.

Also i discovered that withought WHERE clause the code works.How you explain that?

Comment: `subiect='".$row1."'` subject spell is wrong whether its intentionally or it's a mistake ?

Comment: Have you tried to view the query using `echo $sql`?

Comment: yes i ve tried and i also paste it into the console after i saw it

Comment: Nagendra Nigade that  is not a mistake ,it s romanian :))

Comment: ok..cool..Can you check with this code, so that we can cofirmly say its not about `sql error` : `if (!mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT poza1,poza2,poza3,poza4,poza5,poza6 FROM postari WHERE utilizator='".$row2."' AND subiect='".$row1."' AND id2='".$row3."'"))
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }`

Comment: nope the sql it s ok;

Comment: this is all it s returning 

0 
from my num_row verification

Comment: i replaced $con with $conn

Comment: Specify static values to $row1, $row2, $row3 and check. Make sure, the values on utilizator, subiect and id2 columns matches $row2, $row1 and $row3 respectively.

Comment: they match cause i executed the query in console and there it works

Comment: Try using OR clause instead of AND and see if it returns any rows.

Comment: BTW since you wrap the $sql variable with double quotes (") you can just write `='$row2'` instead of  `='".$row2."'` It may increase code readability (IMHO at least)

Comment: STATIC $row1=fgets($dc,120);  like this  SAI KIRAN?

Comment: Like this... $row1 = 'subiect value'; $row2 = 'utilizator value'; $row3 = 'id2 value';

Comment: BTW there is no need to break and concate that `$sql`  string. Simply use `"SELECT poza1, poza2, poza3, poza4, poza5, poza6 FROM postari WHERE utilizator='$row2' AND subiect='$row1' AND id2='$row3'"`. As far as you use `"double quotes"` you don't have to concate any variable to string.

Answer (score 2):

Is the password empty on purpose?

Try adding

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Also, according to https://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.query.php, this may help:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    echo $result->num_rows;
    /* close result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

If you are using several result-returning queries, close previous results with `->close();`

Comment: You should update your answer to use the OO style, as he is using that. That'd be `$conn->connect_errno` in that case.

Comment: this should be a comment also.

Comment: yes it is empty because i use wamp server and i never changed the pass

Comment: the default pass is ''

Comment: My last update does not fit properly in a comment. Please see updated answer